# How to make EF CodeFirst enabled WCF to work with WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How can I take advantage of EF Codefirst on a WCF app that being consumed in a WPF application. What I want is something closer to DbDomainService doing in the latest Silverlight RIA Services, but can I use that in a typical WPF app so that this DbDomainService take care of the EF changes back to the DB?
I am also seeing some hints on using WCF DataServices exposing DbContext. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/21/using-wcf-data-services-with-entity-framework-4-1-and-code-first.aspx

But I couldnt locate any proper working sample or references.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third common assembly containing the body classes, then send them over the wire filled with data to be serialized.

[Here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/sharing-validation-code-between-a-wpf-client-a-wcf-service-and-entity-framework-4-1-using-data-annotations/) is a good article regarding your topic.